# How many ways can you arrange all letters in the word "management" so that at least one "m" is adjacent to one "a"?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

This permutation question appears harder than it seems.

I first to combine a set of "m" and "a" together. Then subtract all cases where "ma" and the other "ma", or "am" and the other "am" as they can switch places. Then subtract the "ama", "mam" cases.

Eventually, get lost in the numerous duplicate cases, can someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take out an $mn$ and consider it one letter. Then arrange the rest of the letters including our new $mn$. Then arrange $mn$. Don't forget to uncount duplicates!

Comment: My apologies, I meant "m" and "a".

Comment: Do the compliment which will be easier

Comment: How should I do that, my brain kind stopped functioning right now.

Comment: @Kevin Beware! There has been a mistake in my solution as Torsten pointed out. I now fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following, we try to solve the compliment problem by *constructing* all permutations of $\mathtt {management}$ with *no* adjacent pair of $\mathtt a$ and $\mathtt m$.

1. Form each of the $6 = \frac {4!} {2!2!}$ permutations of the word $\mathtt {aamm}$. They all have an adjacent pair of $\mathtt a$ and $\mathtt m$, and

   - two of them have one such adjacent pair, namely $\mathtt {aamm}$ and $\mathtt{mmaa}$,
   - two of them have two such adjacent pairs, namely $\mathtt {amma}$ and $\mathtt{maam}$, and
   - two of them have three such adjacent pairs, namely $\mathtt {amam}$ and $\mathtt {mama}$.
2. Insert in each of these words gap symbols where you want to separate such adjacent pairs, e.g. $\mathtt {aa–mm}$ and $\mathtt {a–mm–a}$. Then *interpret* every letter-gap combination *as one character*, e.g. $\mathtt {aa–mm}$ has the character “$\mathtt {a–}$” in it. Of the resulting $4$-character words, there are now

   - two gap-words with one gap,
   - two gap-words with two gaps, and
   - two gap-words with three gaps.
3. Distribute each of these gap-words on the $9$, $8$ or $7$ slots that remain from the ten characters of length in a permutation of $\mathtt{management}$ after accounting for letter-gap combinations (considering that a letter-gap combination is supposed to occupy two characters). There are

   - $126 = {9 \choose 4}$ ways to distribute $4$ characters on $9$ slots,
   - $70 = {8 \choose 4}$ ways to distribute $4$ characters on $8$ slots,
   - $35 = {7 \choose 4}$ ways to distribute $4$ characters on $7$ slots.
4. *Reinterpret* in each of these distributions the letter-gap combinations again as *two* characters. Then remove in each the gap symbols and put in the remaining letters on the slots that are still vacant. There are $180 = \frac {6!} {2!2!}$ permutations of the word $\mathtt {eegnnt}$, so there are $180$ ways to put in the remaining letters in order.

Now you should have counted the number of ways to rearrange the letters of $\mathtt {management}$ such that there is *no* adjacent pair of the letters $\mathtt a$ and $\mathtt m$. I hope I didn’t count any doubles by mistake.

My answer would then be that there are
$$83 160 = (2·126 + 2·70 + 2·35)·180$$
ways to do this. That would be the complement of your problem. Since there are $226800 = \frac {10!} {2!2!2!2!}$ permutations of $\mathtt {management}$, you end up with
$$143 640 = 226 800 - 83 160$$
ways to rearrange the letters of $\mathtt {management}$ with at least one adjacent pair of the letters $\mathtt a$ and $\mathtt m$.

Combinatorics isn’t my thing, though, so better check my answer twice for any mistakes.

*Update*. See? I told you combinatorics wasn’t my thing. Torsten has found that I *did* count a lot of stuff twice – many thanks! I have now fixed my solution. Since I get the same numbers as Torsten now, I feel quite confident that the solution now is correct.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant solution, thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I think there is a mistake. You overcount at the beginning of step 4 when you remove the gap: Say you've distributed AA-MM to slots 1,2,x,9,10, where x is any slot between 3 and 8, then once you've removed the gap, these are indistinguishable but you still count them as different. I think the answer for the complement is actually 83'160, hence for the OP 143'640. I'll add an aswer to get that number with a slightly different way, but it would be cool if you could fix that within this method.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg You’re right. Nice to see you’re still active.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I have now fixed my solution – I got the same numbers as you now. Many thanks for the correction and upvote for your solution!

Comment: Wow, you guys are so good! Wish I could become that good at math one day.

Comment: That's an interesting way to fix it, and I am relieved it gives the same number as mine now. It's just a coincidence I've been tutoring a student in combinatorics recently, and after struggling significantly (and embarrassingly in front of my student) with this kind of problems, I learned of the method I used in my answer. -- @k.stm: Do you mean I've been not very active on this site recently, or do we know each other some other way?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I once was in your bureau to borrow a copy of Lam’s *First Course in Noncommutative Rings* and we’ve seen each other once or twice on some other occasions, maybe talked a bit. If you’d see me, my face would be familiar, I guess. Anyway, I didn’t realize that you were active *here*, I know some of your posts on mathoverflow from back in 2013/2014. Since that time, I just assumed you were doing something completely different. And it’s nice to see you’re still doing some mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to compute the complement, i.e. how many ways there are to arrange the letters with *no* MA or AM.

First, distribute the other letters EENNGTT; as noted in the other answer, there are $\dfrac{10!}{2!2!2!2!} = 180$ ways to do this.

Write them down and put slots where the remaining M's and A's could go, like:

_E_E_N_N_G_T_

So there are in principle $7$ slots for the remaining letters. Now we either

- choose four of the slots, and then distribute the letters in them (automatically no MA or AM): $\binom{7}{4} \cdot \dfrac{4!}{2!2!} = 210$ options, or
- choose three of the slots, then choose one of the three chosen one for a double letter, then choose whether we want a double M or double A (as MA and AM are forbidden): $\binom{7}{3} \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 210$, or
- choose two of the slots; if one contained three or four of our MAMA, we could not avoid an adjacent pair, so both have to have a two letters in them, i.e. one of them will have to have AA and the other MM in it; choose which one: $\binom{7}{2} \cdot 2 = 42$
- if we chose just one slot for the AAMM, we could not avoid adjacent M and A, so that's it.

In total, we have $210+210+42=462$ options. Multiply with $180$ for the distribution of the other letters, gives

$$462 \cdot 180 = 83'160$$

ways to reorder the letters without MA or AM. Since the total number of arrangements is $\dfrac{10!}{2!2!2!2!} = 226'800$, the answer to your question is

$$226'800-83'160=143'640.$$